# How to download the flat file from GitHub?

Tags: git, wget

I'm trying to download the flat text file from GitHub to local path.

```
wget  HTTP://GitHub..../exercise/tree/master/..txt
```

After running the command i see the file downloaded with HTML tags.

How do I get the file content alone downloaded from the Git path?

Comment: You want the `https://github.com/.../.../raw/...` or `raw.githubusercontent.com/...` URL. When you view the file on GitHub there's a ‘Raw’ button that will give you the URL.

Comment: I presume `https://github.com/user/repository/raw/branch/filename` also work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well actually thats pretty easy. Use this link format:

`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/<username>/<repo>/<branch>/folder/filename.c`

Edit: thx to the comment

Comment: isn't it `<username>/<repo>/`?